# JQuery Click event crashes program with no console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT**

In a game I am creating I use the next question button to move onto other questions in the grid if the user is having trouble with the current one. At the moment I have had real problems with it as it keeps on crashing my program, and not giving any console errors. The last problem I had with it was that it said "too much recursion". Since then I thought I had sorted the problem, but I have just done a few tests and it crashes every time.

This is the click event for the button...

```
//Next question click event
$('.next-question').bind("click", function() {
    $('td').removeClass('highlight-problem');
    shuffleEqually(listOfWords);
    shuffleEqually(nextWordIndexes);
    var rndWord = nextWordIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random())];
    var rndWord = nextWordIndexes[2];
    //Adds and removes nesesary classes
    $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('highlight-problem');
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wrong-letter').removeClass('wrong-word').removeClass('right-letter');
    var spellSpace = $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').hasClass('right-word');
    if (spellSpace) {
        $('.next-question').trigger('click');
    } else {
        $("#hintSound").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
        hintSound.play();
        $("#hintPic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
        $('#hintPicTitle').attr('title', listOfWords[rndWord].hint);
    }
});
```

I think it may have something to do with the if statement, but have tried changing it to this..

```
if (spellSpace == false) {

    $("#hintSound").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
    hintSound.play();
    $("#hintPic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
    $('#hintPicTitle').attr('title', listOfWords[rndWord].hint);
}
```

and it makes it even worse

ShuffleEqually:

```
//Shuffles words to randomize
shuffleEqually(nextWordIndexes);
var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

function shuffleEqually(a1, a2) {
    var arrays = [];
    if (typeof a1 === 'object' && a1.length > 0) {
        arrays.push(a1);
    }
    if (typeof a2 === 'object' && a2.length > 0) {
        arrays.push(a2);
    }
    var minLength = arrays[0].length;
    jQuery.each(arrays, function (i, a) {
        minLength = a.length < minLength ? a.length : minLength;
    });
    var randoms = [];
    for (i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        randoms.push(Math.random());
    }
    jQuery.each(arrays, function (i, a) {
        var i = minLength;
        while (i--) {
            var p = parseInt(randoms[i] * minLength);
            var t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[p];
            a[p] = t;
        }
    });
};
```

Hint sound:

```
var hintSound = $("#hintSound")[0];
```

Comment: How is it crashing? What do you mean of **crash**?

Comment: what browser is crashing? I have similar problem right now - Firefox crashes on click event. But only Firefox.

Comment: When I input the next word after using the button it gets stuck on that word and won't move on @MD.Unicorn

Comment: Oh really. Shall I go back to just using a normal click event then? @oyatek

Comment: @Milo-J no! jQuery is not to blame!

Comment: You should debug the javascript code. Use Firebug (for Firefox) or Google Chrome (press F12) and set a breakpoint in your click event. You can then follow the code and see what is happenning.

Comment: perhaps the body of `shuffleEqually` is what causes the problem?

Comment: mine Firefox just crashes without any errors in console when I click [x] close button on JS modal window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is an infinite loop, plain and simple.

```
$('.next-question').bind("click", function() {
// binds click...
...


if (spellSpace) {
    $('.next-question').trigger('click');
    // triggers click ON THE SAME ELEMENT COLLECTION (same selector)
```

You want to refine this. I assume you want the trigger to work on the next question, so I suggest changing the second statement to:

```
 $(".next-question").eq(($(".next-question").index($(this)) + 1) % $(".next-question").length).trigger("click");
```

You have a second infinite loop in shuffleEqually:

```
   jQuery.each(arrays, function (i, a) {
    var i = minLength;
    while (i--) {
        var p = parseInt(randoms[i] * minLength);
        var t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[p];
        a[p] = t;
    }
```

Change the while condition to have a limiting value, or it will loop endlessly (as a decrement operation always succeeds).

Comment: The thing is I don't even really need the trigger('click'). Check edit @user1800246

Comment: You'll need to provide the code for shuffleEqually and hintSound.play() for us to be able to offer another possible loop trail, as, at the moment, I have no idea what they do or how they do it.

Comment: What if I just wanted to take the trigger out completely so it was just an if statement, not an if,else? @user1800246

Comment: Take the trigger out completely, it won't change the issue that you have a second infinite loop in shuffleEqually() ;-)

Comment: So just leave the if part blank? @user1800246

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19745/discussion-between-milo-j-and-user1800246)